# V-container do not apply fluid

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I dont understand why v-container do not apply fluid option. It always behaves as usual container. Here is code from my App.vue

```
<template>

  <v-app id="main" :style="{background: $vuetify.theme.themes[theme].background}">
    <v-container fluid="true">

    </v-container>


  </v-app>
</template>
```

I have tried many ways  like :fluid="true, or only fluid but it still acts as usual container. After inspecting page I have noticed that it seems like browser is interpretating container class before container--fluid and overlaying it's max width. as on screenshot below. Is there any way to solve this issue? I'm using firefox for inspecting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering simmilar issue in future:

For learning project I've installed both boostrap-vue and vuetify. When I removed bootstrap vue dependencies container started to act as expected.